# Export windows account list from bitvise SSH server control panel

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, server, sshd

In our server, we have Bitvise SSH server,

[image: WinssHD Setting]

We do have more than 150 windows accounts, with each account different directory has been mapped. Now I want to export the user account list and it's mapping. The question may sound silly, but anyone can help me with exporting the windows account user list with all the other existing details?

[image: Windows account details]

Answer (score 1):

As per [here](https://www.bitvise.com/wug-wcfg), [here](https://www.bitvise.com/files/BssCfgManip-PowerShell.txt) and [here](https://bvdl.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/BssCfg726.html):

```
#you may need to put your server version here like BssCfg721
$cfg = new-object -com "BssCfg726.BssCfg726"

$cfg.LoadServerSettings()

#this exports all windows accounts to csv file
$cfg.settings.access.winAccounts | Export-Csv 'c:\export.csv'
```

Comment: A `#Requires -RunAsAdministrator` could be helpful and since the lengthy property help is always the same `$cfg.settings.access.winAccounts | Select * -ExcludeProperty help |  Export-Csv 'c:\export.csv'` will reduce output to a usable length.